# Centered layout not responsive

Tags: css

I am developing a website with a centered layout, *i.e. a 3 column grid with the websites content in the middle column (50%) and a 25% empty columns to the left an right.*

So far, it looks pretty good in a full-sized browser. However, if I reduce the browser window's size (or use a mobile viewport) the 25% columns remain to use space. Is there a possibility by which in smaller environments the 25% columns gradually reduce their size to zero?

Or is the grid-approach bad?

Comment: You have used custom width or Bootstrap row , column?

Comment: please post a sample of your code

Answer (score 0):

Try @media ([Mozilla CSS - media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)).

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .col1 {...}
  .col2 {...}
  .col3 {...}
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col1 {...}
  .col2 {...}
  .col3 {...}
}
```